# angular multiple recursive $http query

Tags: angularjs

I use Angular 1.5.

I query a first web service ("/institutions") who return me the list of institutions :

```
  http://localhost:8080/erecolnat/v1/institutions

  [ {
        "institutionid" : 9,
        "institutioncode" : "FEN",
        "links" : [{
                "rel" : "self",
                "href" : "http://localhost:8080/erecolnat/v1/institutions/9"
            }, {
                "rel" : "collections",
                "href" : "http://localhost:8080/erecolnat/v1/institutions/9/collections"
            }
        ]
    }, {
        "institutionid" : 10,
        "institutioncode" : "MHNAIX",
        "links" : [{
                "rel" : "self",
                "href" : "http://localhost:8080/erecolnat/v1/institutions/10"
            }, {
                "rel" : "collections",
                "href" : "http://localhost:8080/erecolnat/v1/institutions/10/collections"
            }
        ]
    }, 
      ..........
]
```

Now I need for each institution to query the "/institutions/XX/collections" web service to get the collections of this institution and to save the data inside the institution.

```
http://localhost:8080/erecolnat/v1/institutions/4/collections

[ {
    "@collectionID": ​1,
    "collectioncode": "CHE",
    "type": "h",
    "collectionName": "Herbarium specimens of Société des Sciences Naturelles et Mathématiques de Cherbourg (CHE)",
    "links": [{
                "rel": "self",
                "href": "http://localhost:8080/erecolnat/v1/collections/4"
            }]
} ]
```

The problem is who to pass a parameter to the second $http to know where to save data like this :

```
angular.module('interfaceApp').service('services', function($rootScope,$http,$q ) {

    this.getInstitutions = function(){  
        var getHrefCollections = function(links){
             for(var l in links){
                if(links[l]["rel"] == "collections"){
                   return links[l]["href"];
                }
             }
             return null ;
        };

        var url = $rootScope.api +"institutions";
        return $http({
             method: 'GET',
             url: url
        }).then(function successCallback(response) {
             for(var i in response.data){
                var url = getHrefCollections( response.data[i]["links"] );
                $http({ method: 'GET', url: url }).then(
                   function successCallback(response /* how to pass a parameter her */) {

                      console.log(response.data); // OK
                      // how to put this data in the good place ( at response.data[i]["collections"] for example )
                   }
                );

             }

             return response ;
        }, function errorCallback(response) {
             console.log(response) ;

        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I understand you correctly I would do the following:

```
var url = $rootScope.api +"institutions";
return $http({
    method: 'GET',
    url: url
}).then(
    function successCallback(response) {
        var promises = [];

        for(var i in response.data){
            var url = getHrefCollections( response.data[i]["links"] );
            promises.push( //Push the promises into an array
                $http({ method: 'GET', url: url })
            );
        }

        return $q.all(promises); // Resolve all promises before going to the next .then
    }, 
    function errorCallback(response) {
        console.log(response);
    }
).then(
    function(resultArray) {
        console.log(resultArray); // resultArray is an array (IN ORDER OF CALLING) with the results from all the promises
    },
    function(error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
);
```

So in your resultArray, the index of the result will still be the same as the index you've called it at in `successCallback`, this way you can link it back to your original institution

Comment: You were faster than me sire!